# Add image using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to put an image up for my header. I currently have it set as a background image, which is repeating. Obviously, I'm doing it wrong. What is the correct img code?

Comment: If you want to use `background-image`, but don't want to repeat, use `background-repeat:no-repeat`. Other than that, I'm not really sure what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#header { background: url(path/to/your/image.jpg) no-repeat; }
```

Comment: The long form of this would be: `background-image:url(image.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {background: url(your image.png) no-repeat;}
```

and if you want to give padding or margin to any inline-element;
don't forgot to used inline-block property. It is very useful.